# Laravel - eloquent.saved event for model is not getting fired

Tags: laravel, eloquent, webhooks, laravel-events

## Issue description

I have been trying to get [captainhook](https://github.com/mpociot/captainhook) to work for a model and was not able to do so. Captainhook is a php library that let's adding URLs and eloquent or custom events for sending event data to those URLs we specify based on the events as a HTTP post request.

I'm not sure where I'm doing a mistake but I assume Laravel is not firing `eloquent.saved` or any other events. I followed all the exact instructions mentioned in readme.

Here are my project files that might help resolve the issue:

Any help is greatly appreciated.

## php artisan hook:list

```
+----+-----------+------------------------+----------------------------+
| id | tenant_id | url                    | event                      |
+----+-----------+------------------------+----------------------------+
| 7  |           | http://localhost:10000 | eloquent.saved \App\Vessel |
+----+-----------+------------------------+----------------------------+
```

## composer.json

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": [
  "framework",
  "laravel"
],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
  "laravel/framework": "5.2.39",
  "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0",
  "venturecraft/revisionable": "1.*",
  "maknz/slack": "^1.7",
  "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^5.2",
  "snowfire/beautymail": "dev-master",
  "mpociot/captainhook": "~2.0",
  "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
  "predis/predis": "^1.1",
  "torann/currency": "^0.3.0",
  "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~6.0"
},
"require-dev": {
  "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
  "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
  "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
  "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
  "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
},
"autoload": {
  "classmap": [
    "database",
    "app/Libraries/ImageUploaderPHP"
  ],
  "psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/"
  },
  "files": [
    "app/Support/helpers.php"
  ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
  "classmap": [
    "tests/TestCase.php"
  ]
},
"scripts": {
  "post-root-package-install": [
    "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
  ],
  "post-create-project-cmd": [
    "php artisan key:generate"
  ],
  "post-install-cmd": [
    "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
    "php artisan optimize"
  ],
  "post-update-cmd": [
    "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
    "php artisan optimize"
  ]
},
"config": {
  "preferred-install": "dist",
  "process-timeout": 0
}
}
```

## **.env**

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=1yoaL71DDzGvey0BwVy25hySFMdBaEoA

DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=myfyba
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis
REDIS_HOST=localhost
....
```

## config/captain_hook.php

```
<?php

/**
 * This file is part of CaptainHook arrrrr.
 *
 * @license MIT
 */

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Event listeners
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array allows you to define all events that Captain Hook should
    | listen for in the application. By default, the Captain will just
    | respond to eloquent events, but you may edit this as you like.
    */
    'listeners' => ['eloquent.*'],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Webhook filter closure
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your webhooks are scoped to a tenant_id, you can modify
    | this filter function to return only the webhooks for your
    | tenant. This function is applied as a collection filter.
    | The tenant_id field can be used for verification.
    |
    */
    'filter' => function ($webhook) {
        return true;
    },

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Webhook data transformer
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The data transformer is a simple function that allows you to take the
    | subject data of an event and convert it to a format that will then
    | be posted to the webhooks. By default, all data is json encoded.
    | The second argument is the Webhook that was triggered in case
    | you want to transform the data in different ways per hook.
    |
    | You can also use the 'Foo\Class@transform' notation if you want.
    |
    */
    'transformer' => function ($eventData, $webhook) {
        return json_encode($eventData);
    },

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Webhook response callback
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The response callback can be used if you want to trigger
    | certain actions depending on the webhook response.
    | This is unused by default.
    |
    | You can also use the 'Foo\Class@handle' notation if you want.
    |
    */
    'response_callback' => function ($webhook, $response) {
        // Handle custom response status codes, ...
    },

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Logging configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Captain Hook ships with built-in logging to allow you to store data
    | about the requests that you have made in a certain time interval.
    */
    'log' => [
        'active' => true,
        'storage_quantity' => 50,
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for that package say Eloquent will fire an event named `eloquent.updated \App\User` for `App\User` model's `updated` event but it will actually fire an event named `eloquent.updated: App\User`.

Try changing your webhook to:

`eloquent.saved: App\Vessel`

Comment: +1 Damn that worked. Thanks a lot. Can you tell me where did you learn this from documentation or else where?

Comment: `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model@fireModelEvent` ... `$event = "eloquent.{$event}: ".static::class;` that handles firing the events, so its where they are named by eloquent.